# Add values to spinner from ArrayList

Tags: android, spinner

I am trying to add values to my spinner dropdown on my android application. I want these values to come from a database table that display user's details, I want the dropdown to show the user's name.

My php works fine and returns the names, however I can't figure out the issue with my code. The php file returns the names but I can't get these added to the spinner:

```
public void setUpWaiterSpinner() {
        final ArrayList<String> listWaiters = new ArrayList<String>();
        String url = "hidden";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("waiters");

                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        final JSONObject orderObj = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        String waiterName = orderObj.getString("name");
                        listWaiters.add(waiterName);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(OrderConfirm.this, "Oops!" +error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("table", "0");
                return params;
            }

        };

        MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
        ArrayAdapter<String> waiter_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listWaiters);
        WaiterSpinner.setAdapter(waiter_adapter);

    }
```

Can anyone see the issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're creating the adapter with the list but your list only get the items after the request is completed. One of the solutions is to create the adapter before the request statement:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> waiter_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listWaiters);
WaiterSpinner.setAdapter(waiter_adapter);
```

And inside `onResponse`, after you add the items to the list, call `waiter_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Thanks for the response!

When I move:

ArrayAdapter<String> waiter_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listWaiters);
WaiterSpinner.setAdapter(waiter_adapter);

to the onCreate method I am unable to access it from the onResponse() method within my setUpWaiterSpinner() method

Comment: Create calss variable: private ArrayAdapter<String>  mAdapter;  and you can use it in any methode.